# Performance of query on indexed Boolean column vs Datetime column

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, mariadb

Is there a notable difference in query performance, if the index is set on `datetime` type column, instead of `boolean` type column (and querying is done on that column)?

In my current design I got 2 columns:

- `is_active` TINYINT(1), **indexed**
- `deleted_at` DATETIME

query is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE is_active = 1;`

Would it be any slower, if I made an index on `deleted_at` column instead, and ran queries like this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE deleted_at is null;` ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect any significant difference. But why don't you just run some benchmarks?

Comment: An index on a boolean flag is virtually useless -- the Optimizer will decide that it is faster to do a table scan.  (I don't know about `NULLs` on a non-boolean column.)

Comment: @RickJames this is not true and verry dependent on the distribution of data. The example above could have 100 rows with is_active = 1 and 1000000 rows is_active = 0. Then it would make a big deference. So as almost always with indexes it depends on the data

Comment: @Patrick - I tentatively believe these: (Case 1):`INDEX(active)` will be used only for `WHERE active=1`.  (Case 2:) `INDEX(active, foo)` will usually be used for `WHERE active=either_value AND foo...`

Comment: And... (Case 3):  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` probably prefers any index that is "covering"; this would include `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE active=0;` Hence, this overrides Case 1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a MariaDB (10.0.19) benchmark with 10M rows (using the [sequence plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/)):

```
drop table if exists test;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `is_active` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `is_active` (`is_active`),
    INDEX `deleted_at` (`deleted_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
    select seq id
        , rand(1)<0.5 as is_active
        , case when rand(1)<0.5 
            then null
            else '2017-03-18' - interval floor(rand(2)*1000000) second
        end as deleted_at
    from seq_1_to_10000000;
```

To measure the time I use `set profiling=1` and run `show profile` after executing a query. From the profiling result I take the value of `Sending data` since everything else is altogether less than one msec.

**TINYINT** index:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE is_active = 1;
```

Runtime: ~ **738 msec**

**TIMESTAMP** index:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE  deleted_at is null;
```

Runtime: ~ **748 msec**

Index size:

```
select database_name, table_name, index_name, stat_value*@@innodb_page_size
from mysql.innodb_index_stats 
where database_name = 'tmp'
  and table_name = 'test'
  and stat_name = 'size'
```

Result:

```
database_name | table_name | index_name | stat_value*@@innodb_page_size
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
tmp           | test       | PRIMARY    | 275513344 
tmp           | test       | deleted_at | 170639360 
tmp           | test       | is_active  |  97107968
```

Note that while TIMESTAMP (4 Bytes) is 4 times as long as TYNYINT (1 Byte), the index size is not even twice as large. But the index size can be significant if it doesn't fit into memory. So when i change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` from `1G` to `50M` i get the following numbers:

- TINYINT: ~ **960 msec**
- TIMESTAMP: ~ **1500 msec**

## Update

To address the question more directly I did some changes to the data:

- Instead of TIMESTAMP I use DATETIME
- Since entries are usually rarely deleted I use `rand(1)<0.99` (1% deleted) instead of `rand(1)<0.5` (50% deleted)
- Table size changed from 10M to 1M rows.
- `SELECT COUNT(*)` changed to `SELECT *`

Index size:

```
index_name | stat_value*@@innodb_page_size
------------------------------------------
PRIMARY    | 25739264
deleted_at | 12075008
is_active  | 11026432
```

Since 99% of `deleted_at` values are NULL there is no significant difference in index size, though a non empty DATETIME requires 8 Bytes (MariaDB).

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE is_active = 1;      -- 782 msec
SELECT * FROM test WHERE deleted_at is null; -- 829 msec
```

Dropping both indexes both queries execute in about 350 msec. And dropping the `is_active` column the `deleted_at is null` query executes in 280 msec.

Note that this is still not a realistic scenario. You will unlikely want to select 990K rows out of 1M and deliver it to the user. You will probably also have more columns (maybe including text) in the table. But it shows, that you probably don't need the `is_active` column (if it doesn't add additional information), and that any index is in best case useless for selecting non deleted entries.

However an index can be usefull to select deleted rows:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE is_active = 0;
```

Executes in 10 msec with index and in 170 msec without index.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE deleted_at is not null;
```

Executes in 11 msec with index and in 167 msec without index.

Dropping the `is_active` column it executes in 4 msec with index and in 150 msec without index.

So if this scenario somehow fits your data the conclusion would be: Drop the `is_active` column and don't create an index on `deleted_at` column if you are rarely selecting deleted entries. Or adjust the benchmark to your needs and make your own conclusion.

Comment: I admire your answer! Very detailed information, with testing and summary! Thank you.

Comment: This is nice, but it is not what the user asked about.  OP is doing `SELECT *` which will not use the index (at least for `status`).  You are using `SELECT COUNT(*)` will be "Using index", that is, using only the index.

Comment: I think the answer is answering exactly what I have asked for. I don't know what the confusion is all about.

Comment: @RickJames I agree that the first version of my answer could lead to wrong conclusions. But as you will see in the update, MariaDB is using a "boolean" index even when it shouldn't. And it is usefull for selecting deleted rows.

Comment: At first, the tests involved 50% each way.  Now that you have a much smaller percentage, the Optimizer will switch to using the index.  _This_ is the thing to point out.

Comment: @RickJames MariaDB seems to use the index in either case: For 99% non deleted rows (is_active = 1) and 1% deleted rows (is_active = 0). Or how would you explain the fact, that dropping the index decreases the execution time?

Comment: `SELECT *` ?  Or `SELECT COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @RickJames `SELECT *`! Just tested with MySQL 5.6.21 at work. And it shows the same behaviour Dropping the indexes decreases the runtime by almost a half.

Answer (score 0):

I think `is_active` would be faster, but it is something you could test on a million rows.