# Do I need a boolean column when I have a date time column for the type of "IsDeleted" columns?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

Let's say I have a table called `Product` and the rows in this table should be deleted logically.

Means that the table must have an `IsDeleted` column.
Let's also say I want to store the date & time that a row has been deleted (logically), therefore, the table must have another (nullable) column called '`DeletedOn`'.

**My question is**: In this style, do I need to have the '`IsDeleted`' column? When I have the '`DeletedOn`' column? (When the '`DeletedOn`' column is null, then the row is not deleted, and when it's not null, the row is deleted. So, I think that we do not need the '`IsDeleted`' column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `DeletedOn IS NULL` or `IsDeleted=0` will almost give your similar performance, `bit` might have a small edge as explained in this [question (**Performance of query on indexed Boolean column vs Datetime column**)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875220/performance-of-query-on-indexed-boolean-column-vs-datetime-column) on stackoverflow. But it will not be that significant.

In case of additional `bit` column, you have to think about maintaining the integrity, via triggers or via computed column, which leads to more complication in your code.

> In this style, do I need to have the 'IsDeleted' column? When I have
>   the 'DeletedOn' column?

As per my suggestion, if you are keeping the deleted on date, you don't need an extra column.